# How to store a List in a Django model

Tags: python, django, model, one-to-many

How can I store a list of `Livre` for each `User` in my Django `model.py`?

Which looks like:

```
class Livre(models.Model):
    auteur = models.ForeignKey(Auteur)
    titre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    genre = models.ForeignKey(Genre)
    publish_date = models.DateField()
```

I want my `User` can as much `Livre` as they want (0 is possible):

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Lecteur(User):
    bibliotheque = models.??????(Livre)
```

... without touching the `Livre` model.

To make is short I want a OneToMany relationship from `User` to `Livre`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `ManyToManyField` in the User model.

You want in fact a `ManyToMany` relation rather than a `OneToMany` relation, because you want multiple users be able to have the same Livre linked to them, right?

If not, you could restrict that by overriding the `save()` method (just add checks), or you could argue that this should be in fact the responsibility of Livre, and add `ForeignKey` there.

You can find more about `ManyToManyField` here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: You are completly right the ManyToMany fits better with my problem. Thanks for your light ch3ka.